Building dApp To Allow Users to Customize and Deploy Tokens
I have been stuck for quite awhile and cant get past it. I've found some gits of old projects with similar concepts, but none have the features platforms like some I've seen lately, such as: [CoinTools][1] and [20Lab][1]
I've tried going through source of similar sites and downloading them to try to figure it out to no avail. I would like to have a platform where users can completely customize their token rather then just add name, signal, and supply.
How do others offer full customizations such as:
Pick tax %, Add multiple tax wallets, Add Auto LP, Send Tax Fee to ETH, and so forth.
I'm so lost, does anyone have any tips, resources, or anything to help?
If not, does anyone know how to successfully "clone and download" a live site using _Next/Static and webpack? I cant understand the chunks and its driving me nuts! An example of the chunks issue is: https://www.createmytoken.com/token-builder/erc-20/ultimate-token/
If you go to sources I get lost with the random file names

They usually (poorly) just pull in ready made sections from known contracts, or imports that users are supposed to configure. User will often just copy, paste and deploy with their own money, then jump in dex support to ask for help rescuing the eth they've locked in pool with the s- coin who's mechanics they have 0 understanding of. If you are gonna make a site like that please have a firm understanding of how contract components work together yourself and communicate best practices on your site.

You can use a library like OpenZeppelin. Then adding features is just adding an import statement, and inheriting a new base contract. Instead of focusing on adding multiple features first start by having one, then two, etc.
